# What is the proper way to create an attribute_created_at field for a specific rails model field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with an attribute `car`
I want to add a field `car_created_at`
that will have as a value the timestamp of the first time `car` actually assigned a value.
What is the proper way to do that? maybe `after_update` hook?

Answer (score 0):

According to the trusty rails [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks), `after_update` only runs on updates.

`after_save` runs both when created and updated. So I would use that.

And beware that just doing `save` in the hook will cause infinite call stack, meaning `save` will trigger `after_save`, in which `save` is called.

So you will have to use [`update_columns`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns).

```
after_save :touch_car_created

def touch_car_created
  if car_created_at.nil?
    update_columns(car_created_at: Time.zone.now)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to go with `before_save` because this callback get called before object creation and updation.

```
# This callback works only when car value has changed
# and car_created_at is nil.
before_save :assign_car_created_time, if: Proc.new { car_changed? && car_created_at.nil? }

private
# Keep it private so it won't be accessed publicly.

def assign_car_created_time
  # We only need to assign the value
  self.car_created_at = Time.zone.now
end
```

Hope this works for you.